How to use CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt in c for libcrypto.so.1.1?
I changed the linking of my binary from libcrypto.so.10 to libcrypto.so.1.1. I intend to run this binary on RHEL version 8.8. This required me to change AES_ctr128_encrypt() function to CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt(). There is an extra parameter which is the structure block128_f used in this. It has two char arrays and one key field.
My question is that what should I populate in this structure and how to pass it in the function CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt() so that it executes correctly ? I tried passing the structure with null values but it generated a core file during execution.

You don't populate it. The block128_f structure is a predefine encryption function token. If you're encrypting with AES you should use the library-supplied AES_encrypt  symbol. If the appropriate headers are included, it should be available.
